# how to add zero on multiple places in string android

Tags: android, string, time, string-formatting

I want to show number in two digits format anyone please tell me how i can do this using string format

i am doing this but this give me error

```
String formatted = String.format("%02d", list.get(i).toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
String formatted  = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).toString()));
```

Comment: thanks its solve my problem i was not parsing that was the problem i have seen

Comment: Great.. Accept the answer if it worked for you.. vote-up if possible. Happy Coding :)

Comment: ok will you please tell me if i have this 01.12 then how i convert it into 00:00:01.12

Comment: you can pad 01.12 with more 4 zeros and then add `:` after every 2 digits/index use StringBuilder for this

Comment: or if you can convert seconds into milliseconds the use `int millis = 5000; SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS"); String time = df.format(millis);`

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument to String.format should be an integer here. Try

```
String formatted = String.format("%02d", list.get(i));
```

(Assuming you have a list of integers).

Comment: i have this 1:1:1.1 how i can convert it into 01:01:01.01?

Comment: This looks like a different question to me. Post a different question or edit your original question if you feel that it is about the same problem. Quick answer: you should loop through your numbers to format them one by one. Think about it hard and try it before asking :-)